# Is there storage limit to Asus Tuf laptops?

Tags: memory, storage, asus

I have the `Asus Tuf Gaming f15(2023)`. Is there any storage limit? Can I install 2TB SSD and 64GB RAM?

Comment: possibly, depends on your model:  have  you looked at the manual? https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-gaming/tuf-gaming/asus-tuf-gaming-f15/techspec/

Comment: you can probably install the disk without concern, but you'll have to consult the manual on the RAM. a lot of OEMs configure limits into the firmware that controls max memory size, so it depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new disk has the same dimensions (or if it fits in) and
the same interface, then there is a 99% chance that it will work.

For the RAM expansion, I suggest to download and run the
[Crucial Scanner](https://www.crucial.com/upgrades).
It will analyze your computer and suggest compatible upgrades.
The Crucial upgrades are guaranteed and reasonably priced,
but if you prefer buying others, ensure that the RAM is of
exactly the same specs as that of the Crucial suggestions.

Without analyzing your computer, the Crucial website
indicated these limits for the RAM:

[image]

For the disk, the largest internal disk it recommends
is this one:

[image]

But I still suggest to run the Crucial Scanner to be sure,
in case your model is not the ASUS TUF Gaming F15 (2022).

Comment: I have `Asus Tuf Gaming f15(2023)(FX507ZU4)`, with preinstalled 512GB SSD and one slot to another one.

Is there any limit of hardware to it?

Comment: I added the limits.